# Standards for HTML layout element class names?

Tags: html, css, standards, microformats

I'm trying to work out how I can make my CSS as de-coupled from my HTML as possible. The way to do that would be to write the basic layout elements in the HTML in a standard way, so that different CSS files could know exactly what the mark-up it's working with will look like without having seen it.

So I was wondering if there exist anywhere a set of standards for how you should name your layout elements and what order to put them in. E.g. a sensible way to mark-up my page would be as follows (note that I'm using HTML5 elements and following [the theory that you should never use IDs for CSS rules](https://github.com/CSSLint/csslint/wiki/Disallow-IDs-in-selectors)):

```
<body>
  <div class="container"> <!-- central "squeeze" for the content -->
    <header>
      <img class="logo" />
      <nav class="primary"></nav> <!-- main navigation -->
    </header>
    <aside class="pre"></aside> <!-- left column -->
    <article class="main"></article> <!-- central main content -->
    <aside class="post"></aside> <!-- right column -->
  </div>
</body>
```

Many pages use something similar to this basic layout. But as you can see, the name of the "container" or "primary" class will vary a lot, as will the use of `<aside>` for columns. Also, there are probably variances in ordering, like some people would put the `<nav>` element after the `<header>` rather than inside it, or the column elements inside the `<article>` element.

Does anyone know of any work that's been done to standardise the ordering and naming of these commonly used layout elements? Like a microformat or something?

Comment: There is no hard and fast rule or universally accepted standard for class names, and there aren't any microformats in use here. Just do what's best for your site, and don't be afraid to use IDs for CSS - they put ID selectors in the language for a reason.

Comment: Where does "the theory that you should never use IDs for CSS rules" come from? Never heard of that one, I don't see how it makes sense. ids are particularly useful for specificity reasons, among other things.

Comment: Theory of never using IDs: https://github.com/stubbornella/csslint/wiki/Disallow-IDs-in-selectors; http://oli.jp/2011/ids/; http://screwlewse.com/2010/07/dont-use-id-selectors-in-css/. This is some very sound theory written by people who know a lot about using CSS in large projects. And I definitely personally agree with it.

Comment: Plenty of other [smart people](http://mattwilcox.net/archive/entry/id/1054/) disagree.

Comment: @Quentin. Yes they do - but they'll come round. =D

Comment: I'm curious why you posted full URLs in comments but masked one of them behind a short URL in the body of your post... there's a limit to comment length but not for questions and answers. Just something I found really odd.

Comment: @BoltClock: lolz. Yes that didn't make any sense. I normally shorten URLs in text generally so they don't break up the flow of reading too much - maybe I shouldn't do that, not sure. In the comment I just didn't get round to it.

Comment: The fastest way to query an element in jQuery is by ID, so there's one really good reason to use ID's.

Comment: @Chris Fletcher: Except that's a scripting concern, not a CSS one...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is an absolute standard, since no two websites are the same.

Allright, some are, but that's not the point. :)

Anyway, since the CSS is made specifically to markup that single website, you can't actually decouple it in such detail. You won't find some ready made CSS sheets that you can just plugin your website to place all those navigation containers.

I think the best way is to come up with a standard for yourself and stick to it. I hope you would be able to find better names than the often used but quite abstract 'container'. And maybe, some day, it will become the defacto standard.

Comment: I suspected this was the case. It's just that a lot of websites do use  a very similar layout (centrally squeezed content, header at top, followed by main nav, followed by main content, with optional left or right column), and so it would be possible to have a standard best mark-up for this. And the more CSS and HTMl documents followed the standard, the easier the job of understanding and editing such documents would become for front-end devs.

Comment: I will write my own standard and publish it on a blog or something in the absence of an existing one, but I'll leave this question here a bit longer before accepting your answer in case someone else knows of something useful.